# How to fix common table expression-CTE and code country

Tags: sql

I am working with some database and I try to execute CTE. In order to do that I first started with this piece of code which worked very well

```
SELECT 
fa.TenDigits,
co.EconomicGroup
FROM dbo.FactTable AS fa
INNER JOIN [DIMENSION].[HS] AS hs ON hs.TenDigits=fa.TenDigits
INNER JOIN [DIMENSION].[Countries] AS co ON co.CountryCodes=fa.CountryCodes
WHERE [Year]='2019'
GROUP BY fa.TenDigits,fa.CountryCodes,co.EconomicGroup
```

Output from  this code is shown in this picture below:

[image]

So next step should  be sum of some values of this database with CTE. So with code above I try to use with CTE below, but something is not good and code does not work well.

```
;WITH MyCTE as
(
SELECT 
fa.TenDigits,
co.CountryCodes,
co.EconomicGroup,
SUM(CustomsDuties_T) AS SumCustomsDuties,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CountryCodes ORDER BY SUM(CustomsDuties_T)DESC) AS RN
FROM dbo.FactTable AS fa
INNER JOIN [DIMENSION].[HS] AS hs ON hs.TenDigits=fa.TenDigits
INNER JOIN [DIMENSION].[Countries] AS co ON co.CountryCodes=fa.CountryCodes
WHERE [Year]='2019'
GROUP BY fa.TenDigits,fa.CountryCodes,co.EconomicGroup
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
WHERE RN<21
```

After executing this code I received this error message:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 218
Column 'DIMENSION.Countries.CountryCodes' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 221
Ambiguous column name 'CountryCodes'.
```

So can anybody help me how to fix this code ?

Comment: You group by `fa.CountryCodes`, but select `co.CountryCodes`

Comment: I try to change but nothing

Comment: After changing I receive this message ' Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 221
Ambiguous column name 'CountryCodes'.'

Comment: That's because you `Partition by CountryCodes`, but which one?

Comment: Yes, this is problem. Thank you!